# Group by in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, group-by

I have 2 tables `Products` and `Invoices`. Each `Products` can be in some `Invoices`.

```
Product:

Id| Name
ـــــــــــــــ
1 | pencil
2 | pen
3 | ruler


Invoice:

Id| ProductID| Serial |Qty
ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ
1 | 1        |100     |5
2 | 1        |200     |6
3 | 2        |300     |8
4 | 3        |400     |18
```

When I write the following query

```
select * , SUM(Invoices.Qty)

FROM Products left outer join Invoices on Products.Id = Invoices.ProductID

Group by Products.Id
```

result:

```
Id| Name  |Id|ProductID| Serial|SUM(Invoices.Qty)
ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ
1 |pencil |2 |1        |200    |11 -> (5+6)
2 |pen    |3 |2        |300    |8
3 |ruler  |4 |3        |400    |18
```

it returns a list of all products that is joined by the **last Invoice**. It calculates the `Qty` correctly but the problem is the selection of the last Invoice. How can I write a query that calculates `Qty` correctly and returns the `Invoices` with the `id` that I want.

**in this example I want the invoice id 1 (serial 100) not 2 (serial 200)**

Comment: Can you show the Both tables structure and what output you want ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff for example if we have 2 invoices with id 10 and 11 it returns that last (invoice with id 11). But I want the Invoice with id 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
(select sum(i3.qty) from Invoices i3 where i3.productId = i.productId)
FROM invoices I
JOIN products P
     on I.productId = P.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'PREVIOUS'
    FROM invoices I2
    where I2.ProductId = I.productId
    and I2.id < I.id
)
```

In this way you get the first invoice about a product. I don't understand if doesn't exist an invoice in you want to show the product. If yes, you must change the query with a left outer join

Comment: Thanks, What should I do if I need an invoice with specific id. for example there is a `Product` having 3 `Invoices` with ids 1, 2, 3 and I need the second invoice means 2. How can I retrieve that record?

Comment: @breceivemail: You must always define a general strategy. Query changes about that. In your question you want the first, but if the aim is different the query will be different.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can use the `MIN` or `MAX` functions to force a specific from the group to be returned:

```
SELECT *, MIN(Invoices.Serial), SUM(Invoices.Qty)
FROM Products LEFT JOIN Invoices ON Products.Id = Invoices.ProductID
GROUP BY Products.Id
```

Comment: My id is not always the minimum. It cab be an Id between a set of ids.